# Neural Network predicts only one class and all output layer activation for testing becomes 0.999~

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I am currently working on creating a Neural Network in Python and I have been stuck to this problem.

- I have balanced my data by upsampling now so data balancing shouldn't be a problem.
- For my labels, there are 8 classes and 354 features. I used one-hot vector per sample to transform class/label 4 into `[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]`
- using sigmoid for 2 hidden layers and output, tried using softmax on output layer but has the same problem

Problem:

- output layer activation/output for validation becomes something like this `[0.99999997, 0.99999997, 0.99999997, 0.99999997, 0.99999997, 0.99999997, 0.99999997, 0.99999997]`
- predicts only 1 class for everything (for this latest run, predicts 2)
- accuracy does not change (because of the thing above)
- error is fluctuating

  Epoch: 119 Error: [255.99999638]
  Epoch: 120 Error: [143.99999741]
  Epoch: 121 Error: [63.99999831]
  Epoch: 122 Error: [3.99999957]
  Epoch: 123 Error: [3.99999955]
  Epoch: 124 Error: [35.99999874]
  Epoch: 125 Error: [255.9999965]

What might be wrong here?

Code for `training()`

```
def train(self, test_set, test_labels, validation_set, validation_label):
    total_error = numpy.zeros((max_epoch, 1))
    # temporary values, use reshape
    size_of_traning_set = len(test_set)
    len_test_set_col = len(test_set[0])
    len_test_label_col = len(test_labels[0])

    for count in range(0, max_epoch):
        random_permutations = numpy.random.permutation(size_of_traning_set)
        for count_2 in range(0, size_of_traning_set):
            random_index = random_permutations[count_2]

            x_in = numpy.reshape(test_set[random_index], (len_test_set_col, 1))
            d_out = numpy.reshape(test_labels[random_index], (len_test_label_col, 1))
            # forward propagation

            # 1st hidden layer
            v_hidden_layer_1 = numpy.add(numpy.dot(self.layer_one_weights, x_in), self.layer_one_bias)
            y_hidden_layer_1 = compute_activation(v_hidden_layer_1)

            # 2nd hidden layer
            v_hidden_layer_2 = numpy.add(numpy.dot(self.layer_two_weights, y_hidden_layer_1), self.layer_two_bias)
            y_hidden_layer_2 = compute_activation(v_hidden_layer_2)

            v_output_layer = numpy.add(numpy.dot(self.output_layer_weights, y_hidden_layer_2), self.output_layer_bias)
            final_output = compute_activation(v_output_layer)
            error_vector = d_out - final_output

            # compute gradient in output layer
            delta_output_x = numpy.multiply(error_vector, final_output)
            one_minus_out = 1 - final_output
            delta_output = numpy.multiply(delta_output_x, one_minus_out)

            # compute gradient in hidden layer 2
            one_minus_y_h2 = 1 - y_hidden_layer_2
            output_layer_weights_trans = numpy.transpose(self.output_layer_weights)
            deriv_hidden_layer_2_x = numpy.multiply(y_hidden_layer_2, one_minus_y_h2)
            deriv_out_layer = numpy.dot(output_layer_weights_trans, delta_output)
            delta_hidden_layer_2 = numpy.multiply(deriv_hidden_layer_2_x, deriv_out_layer)

            # compute gradient in hidden layer 1
            one_minus_y_h1 = 1 - y_hidden_layer_1
            hidden_layer_2_weights_trans = numpy.transpose(self.layer_two_weights)
            deriv_hidden_layer_1_x = numpy.multiply(y_hidden_layer_1, one_minus_y_h1)
            deriv_layer_2 = numpy.dot(hidden_layer_2_weights_trans, delta_hidden_layer_2)
            delta_hidden_layer_1 = numpy.multiply(deriv_hidden_layer_1_x, deriv_layer_2)

            # update weights and biases of output layer
            self.output_layer_weights = self.output_layer_weights + \
                                        numpy.multiply(self.learning_rate, numpy.dot(delta_output,
                                                  numpy.reshape(y_hidden_layer_2, (1, self.number_of_layer_2))))
            self.output_layer_bias = self.output_layer_bias + numpy.multiply(self.learning_rate, delta_output)

            # update weights and biases of hidden layer 2
            self.layer_two_weights = self.layer_two_weights + \
                                        numpy.multiply(self.learning_rate, numpy.dot(delta_hidden_layer_2,
                                                  numpy.reshape(y_hidden_layer_1, (1, self.number_of_layer_1))))
            self.layer_two_bias = self.layer_two_bias + numpy.multiply(self.learning_rate, delta_hidden_layer_2)

            # update weights and biases of hidden layer 1
            self.layer_one_weights = self.layer_one_weights + \
                                     numpy.multiply(self.learning_rate, numpy.dot(delta_hidden_layer_1,
                                               numpy.reshape(x_in, (1, self.number_of_inputs))))
            self.layer_one_bias = self.layer_one_bias + numpy.multiply(self.learning_rate, delta_hidden_layer_1)

        err_sum = numpy.multiply(error_vector, error_vector)
        err_sum = numpy.divide(err_sum, 2)
        total_error[count] = total_error[count] + numpy.sum(err_sum)

        print('Epoch: {} Error: {}'.format(count, total_error[count]))

        if count % 10 == 0 and count != 0:
            self.validate(validation_set, validation_label)
```

Comment: Be sure you *normalize* your data before feeding into your NN. Also, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as why [a wall of code isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code is correct,When you are getting the same output for all classes that means all of the neurons in your hidden layers are learning the same weights in other words the same function, your whole network is doing what just a single neuron can do. this is happens when you initialize all weights with same value, you must start with random different values for each weight.